# Opencv - Filter2D function

Tags: image, opencv, filter, imagefilter

I want to filter an image using my own kernel. Should summary of kernel matrix elements of this filter is equal to 1?

I prepare a kernel. I try it and the result is fine for me. But I don't sure that this kernel is a true matrix for filtering. I read a comment, it says that

```
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
```

this is wrong, it should be

```
1.0/9 1.0/9 1.0/9 
1.0/9 1.0/9 1.0/9
1.0/9 1.0/9 1.0/9
```

My kernel is

```
0  0  0  0  0
1  2  5  2  1
0  0  0  0  0
-1 -2 -5 -2 -1
0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Could you add a little details about why the kernel elements should be 1.0/9.0? Can you paste an excerpt of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should summary of kernel matrix elements of this filter is equal to 1?

If you want the brightness of the convoluted image to be the same, then the sum of all elements of the kernel should be 1, e.g. if you want to blur your image. This is called normalization of the kernel. It's also common for the sum to be 0, e.g. in the case of edge detection.

Your kernel looks like a special case of the [Sobel operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator), which also sums to zero. Examples of other common convolution kernels can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28image_processing%29).

Comment: I want to find edge detection using color change. After reading your answer, I think that my kernel is a reasonable for this work. Thanks.